# How to hide values in a non dependent picklist

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities, custom-object

I have a 'non dependent' picklist where I want to hide certain values based on the year.
The picklist has values from 2000 to 2030 but I want those values to be absent and only show 2023 in the picklist. Is is possible using formula fields or validation rules.
My pick list looks like this.[I want to show the current year only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hndYJ.png)

I have tried using YEAR() and TODAY() function but to no avail.

Comment: Why you need picklist then? you can create formula like YEAR ( TODAY() ) and it will return current year every time.

Comment: yes I thought about it but biz required a picklist although it has been closed. Thanks for the help!!